# Get Array of Values for Non-Contiguous Range

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'd like to be able to get an array of values for just the visible cells on a worksheet. However, the `Range.Value2` property only seems to work with contiguous cells.

What would be an efficient method of getting the visible cell values into a multiple dimensional array? Perhaps we could do some sort of looping over the `Range.Areas`?

If you look at the sample code below, you will see that the `.Value2` property only returns the values for the first `Area` in the `Range`.

Sample output is (you'll see that the visible values is missing the last two rows):

```
All Values:

String1     String2     String3     String4     String5
String6     String7     String8     String9     String10
String11    String12    String13    String14    String15
String16    String17    String18    String19    String20
String21    String22    String23    String24    String25


Visible Values:

String1 String2 String3 String4
String6 String7 String8 String9
```

_

```
    public static void RunTest()
    {
        SetData();
        HideRowsAndColumns();

        Excel.Application excelApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        Excel.Worksheet sht = excelApp.ActiveSheet;
        var usedRange = sht.UsedRange;
        var visibleUsedRange = usedRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible);
        var usedRangeVals = (object[,])usedRange.Value2;
        var visibleUsedRangeVals = (object[,]) visibleUsedRange.Value2; //this doesn't get the full set of values because Value2 does not work with non-contiguous ranges

        string s = "All Values:\n\n" + ArrayToString(usedRangeVals) + "\n\nVisible Values:\n\n" +
                        ArrayToString(visibleUsedRangeVals);


        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }

    private static string ArrayToString(object[,] vals)
    {

        int dim1Start = vals.GetLowerBound(0); //Excel Interop will return index-1 based arrays instead of index-0 based
        int dim1End = vals.GetUpperBound(0);
        int dim2Start = vals.GetLowerBound(1);
        int dim2End = vals.GetUpperBound(1);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = dim1Start; i <= dim1End; i++)
        {
            for (int j = dim2Start; j <= dim2End; j++)
            {
                sb.Append(vals[i, j]);
                if (j != dim2End)
                    sb.Append("\t");
            }
            sb.Append("\n");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static void SetData()
    {
        const int rows = 5;
        const int cols = 5;
        var a = new string[rows, cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                a[i, j] = "String" + (i * cols + j + 1);

        Excel.Application excelApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        Excel.Worksheet sht = excelApp.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Range rng = sht.Range[sht.Cells[1, 1], sht.Cells[rows, cols]];
        rng.Value2 = a;
    }

    private static void HideRowsAndColumns()
    {
        Excel.Application excelApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        Excel.Worksheet sht = excelApp.ActiveSheet;
        var row = (Excel.Range) sht.Rows[3];
        row.Hidden = true;

        var col = (Excel.Range) sht.Columns[5];
        col.Hidden = true;
    }
```

Comment: Have you seen [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465826/how-to-read-the-data-from-non-adjacent-cells-in-excel-using-c-sharp)

Comment: or [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594402/excel-values-from-ranges-with-multiple-areas) or [THIS](http://markquestions.com/questions/811594/c-excel-how-to-copypaste-non-contiguous-ranges-programatically) You could copy the visible range into a new sheet and then read that range using `.Value2`

Comment: thanks. Copying to a new worksheet and then getting .Value2 works great.  However, I hate using the clipboard since it is a system resource and doing so will wipe out any data that was stored on it before the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not want to use any of the methods mentioned in the links that I gave you above and you also do not want to copy the data to a new worksheet then this is the only way I can think of.

**Logic**

1. Open workbook as Read Only. If you are working with active sheet which has hidden rows/columns then [create a copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835014.aspx) ( of the excel file with those rows/columns hidden and then work with that copy.
2. Find the last row/column on the worksheet
3. Loop through the rows/Columns of the worksheet and delete the rows/columns which are not visible
4. You are now left with one contiguous range. Copy that in the array
5. Close the Excel file without saving.

**Note**: I have shown you one example of looping through the rows. You can do a similar thing for columns

**Code**

```
int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells[xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count, 1].End[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row;

for (int i = 1; i <= _lastRow; i++)
{
    if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].Entirerow.Hidden == true)
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].EntireRow.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp); ;
}
```

**Edit**

I am adding this as a separate section and not deleting the above code as it may help any future visitors.

Apparently, OP is fine with the idea of copying visible cells to a new worksheet and then using `.Value2` to store the data into the array as suggested in the comments.

```
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlNewWorkSheet = xlexcel.Worksheets.Add(misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

Excel.Range MyRange = 
xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible,misValue);

MyRange.Copy(xlNewWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1"));
```

Comment: thanks for your help. In spite of having to use the clipboard, I think copying the visible cells to a new worksheet and then using Value2 is the best solution. If you create a new answer or modify this one, then I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @jjdem: I have not deleted the answer but added another answer below it :)